# Explain the gramatical structure of this sentence + use of あまり and より

Tags: grammar, syntax, structure

> （君は）照れを隠すあまりより惨事になってるけど、大丈夫？

The（君は）is just for added context.

I'm having trouble understanding the structure of this sentence. as well as the use of `あまり` and
`より`. From what I can pull, it means either "*Hiding your embaressment is making it even more disastrous though, are you OK?*" or "*You're trying so hard to hide your embaressment that it becoming more disastrous, are you OK?*". So I want a couple things cleared up here.

What are the `あまり` and
`より` doing in the sentence and which words are they modifying? Is `照れを隠す` supposed to be a modifier for `あまり` or is `あまり` a modifier for `照れを隠す`? If `照れを隠す` is an entirely seperate clause, shouldn't it be in the masu stem form or te-form? Would it make sense to put a comma after `あまり`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This あまり is a "formal noun" (形式名詞) that works like a conjunctive. Grammatically, it belongs to the same word class as とき ("when ～"), ため ("for ～'s sake; due to ～"), とおり ("just as ～"), etc. You probably know these don't take a masu-stem or a te-form, either. It's because when a verb comes before these "nouns", it technically forms a relative clause.

Here, あまり means something like "because of extreme ～" or "because one does ～ too much". For example, 驚きのあまり and 驚いたあまり both translate to "since one was too surprised". Technically speaking, 照れを隠す is a relative clause that modifies the noun あまり. It makes perfect sense to put a comma after あまり, and it also makes this sentence more readable, but it's not a requirement, either.

より is simply an adverb that means "more". Here it modifies (惨事に)なる.

Your understanding of the sentence is correct. 照れを隠すあまり means "Because you're hiding your embarrassment too much", and より惨事になってる means "[the situation] has become disastrous even more".